# Transmission Segmentation Fault on 20.04 in non-root mode

Tags: gnome, upgrade, transmission

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and I'm facing a really strange problem with `transmission-gtk`. Here are the characteristics :

- In GUI, Transmission doesn't launch
- Typing `transmission-gtk` in a terminal prints `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, or (less frquently) `Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying`
- But, typing `sudo transmission-gtk` works fine ! (although of course I don't see my torrents)
- Also, `transmission-qt` works fine two !

I already tried purging all transmission-related package and reinstalling them.

System infos : I'm on a Asus Vivobook laptop with Ryzen 5 CPU, Ubuntu 20.04.1 (coming from 18.04.5), and my DM is `Gnome` (not "Ubuntu Gnome", if that's what it's called). Also in case that matters, my upgrade process was slighlty disturbed because of `phpmyadmin` which kept asking for a password I didn't have, so I think it skept the "cleaning" step of the upgrade, but I just `sudo apt autoremove` after the upgrade and everything seemed fine.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day !

Comment: Do you log into a Wayland session ?

Comment: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` prints `wayland` so yes I do

Comment: transmission-gtk does not seem to be Wayland-ready. Does it still crash if you log into x11 sessions ?